# MVC Bundling Error: include bundles from application root instead of server root

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, directory, bundle, root

In my development studio I have my bundle as:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));     

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui")
    .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));
```

When I publish to my production server in a folder "XXX", in IIS, it throws error in the JavaScript below.

[image]

Instead of requesting http://localhost/XXX/Scripts its requesting for http://localhost/Scripts

How can I make it pick from application root folder instead of server root?

Comment: Your screenshot contains errors referencing style sheets not javascript files.

Comment: Also please show the view (or layout) how do you include it.